# How to print odd and even numbers from 2 separate threads synchronize

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

i want to print odd and even numbers from 2 separate threads in synchronize manner in win32 C++. i am using critical section to achieve it, but cn't get the desired result. can be do it using critical section.

Comment: Also a clear description of what `synchronized` means to you could help. Do you mean that the output should be `1,2,3,4...` and each thread is generating either the even or odd numbers?

Comment: The point of synchronization is so things can happen out of order.  I don't recommend this exercise.

Comment: yes, one thread will print even number, while other print odd number. output should be like 1,2,3,4....

Comment: It's more challenging than it sounds at first glance.  Please post up what you have tried and we will help you from there.

Comment: @franji:it's not a homework, just for fun, i have done earlier using mutex, tried using critical section, i find my problem in my implementation and resolve it and pasted the code n it's works fine now.

Comment: you might check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641134/printing-odd-and-even-number-printing-alternately-using-threads-in-c/16272239#16272239

Comment: @vijay: ur solution is not up to the mark, since ur code is printing the values only through even_thread_cs, since ur sharedvariable value always remain 0.

Comment: what is real question? why it is not real question? Actually it is hot interview question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it can be done with critical section only, but in a way that is not obvious.

```
// all in pseudocode:

mutex printMutex;
int printedOdd = 1;

//thread 1
int start = 1;
while(1) {
  lock (printMutex);
  if (printOdd == 1) {
    print ( start );
    start += 2;
    printedOdd = 0;
  } else {
    unlock (printMutex);
    yield();
    continue;
  }
  unlock (printMutex);
}

// thread 2
int start = 2;
while(1) {
  lock (printMutex);
  if (printOdd == 0) {
    print ( start );
    start += 2;
    printedOdd = 1;
  } else {
    unlock (printMutex);
    yield();
    continue;
  }
  unlock (printMutex);
}
```

I do not actually understand the point of doing something like this, but an answer is... an answer:)

Comment: i want to implement it through critical section, not through mutex.

Comment: A critical section is a mutex.

Comment: @david:as far as i know, mutex can be used across inter process and intra process thread synchronization while critical section can be used only synchronize threads in a single process.

Comment: @user1808932 - "i am using critical section to achieve it, but cn't get the desired result." - Post your code and people will help.

Comment: A Win 32 critical section object is a mutex, where I use the generic terminology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion  Did you even note that this answer gives you pseudo code. When you turn it into real code, you can use the mutex of your choice.

Comment: @david:can u suggest me how to implement yield in win32. btw i have resolved my problem, n pasted the working code with the query.