# Semaphores and threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

Program should take 3 filenames as parameters, create 2 threads, first thread reads from first file, second thread reads from second file, and they both write to the third file. Ultimately they should alternate writing each line from the file they are reading to the third file. When I run the program they don't really alternate; sometimes one thread writes all its lines to the file, then the other writes all of it's lines to the file. Sometimes they alternate for one line each, then a couple for one thread, then a couple for the other. Can someone point me in the write direction to get each thread to alternate writing to the file? I find that when I change the 3rd parameter for the sem_init function it affects the way the threads alternate.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define BADFILE  2
#define BADPARAM 3
#define DEBUG    1

sem_t mutex;

typedef struct {
    char *file;
    FILE *mf;
} read_args;

void error(char *msg, int code)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\nAborting.\n", msg);
    exit(code);
}

void *readFile1(void *p)
{

    read_args *param = (read_args *)p;
    FILE *f1;
    char *line;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int lineCount = 1;
    f1 = fopen(param->file, "r");
    if(f1 == NULL)
    {
        error("File not found.", BADFILE);
    }


    while((read = getline(&line, &len, f1)) != -1)
    {  
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        fprintf(param->mf,"%s: %d: %s", param->file, lineCount,line);

#if DEBUG        
        printf("%s: %d: %s", param->file, lineCount,line);
#endif 

        sem_post(&mutex);
        lineCount++;
    } 
    fclose(f1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *readFile2(void *p)
{

    read_args *param = (read_args *)p;
    FILE *f1;
    char *line;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int lineCount = 1;
    f1 = fopen(param->file, "r");
    if(f1 == NULL)
    {
        error("File not found.", BADFILE);
    }
    //sem_wait(&mutex);
    while((read = getline(&line, &len, f1)) != -1)
    {  
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        fprintf(param->mf,"%s: %d: %s", param->file, lineCount,line);

#if DEBUG        
        printf("%s: %d: %s", param->file, lineCount,line);
#endif 

        sem_post(&mutex);
        lineCount++;
    }

    fclose(f1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *f;
    char *mergedfile;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    read_args *p1;
    read_args *p2;
    p1 = malloc(sizeof(read_args));
    p2 = malloc(sizeof(read_args));
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        error("Invalid parameters. Proper use: ./merge <file1> <file2>" 
            " <mergedfile>", BADPARAM);
    }

    p1->file = argv[1];
    p2->file = argv[2];

    mergedfile = argv[3];
    f = fopen(mergedfile, "w");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        error("Can't open file.", BADFILE);
    }
    p1->mf = f;
    p2->mf = f;

    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 3);
    if(pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, readFile1, (void*)p1) < 0)
    {
        error("Can't create first thread", EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, readFile2, (void*)p2) < 0)
    {
        error("Can't create second thread", EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pthread_join(tid1, NULL) < 0)
    {
        error("Can't join first thread", EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pthread_join(tid2, NULL) < 0)
    {
        error("Can't join second thread", EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sem_destroy(&mutex);

    fclose(f);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [printing odd and even number printing alternately using threads in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641134/printing-odd-and-even-number-printing-alternately-using-threads-in-c)

Comment: I'm a new member to the site so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly/according to the rules, but thanks Duck; that fixed it, appreciate the help. Also, sorry if this was a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the semaphore like a mutex.  That will keep one thread writing and the other blocked but there is no guarantee of the order of execution.  As you discovered the same thread can acquire the semaphore many times in a row.  Each thread needs to signal the other that it is their turn to go.  They do this by posting.

If you use a second semaphore you can force the threads to alternate.  Thread1 needs to wait on mutex1 and post to mutex2.  Thread2 waits on mutex2 and posts to mutex1.  Mutex1 needs to be initialize to 1 so it can go first; mutex2 gets initialized to 0 so it has to wait until thread1 runs first and posts before it can do anything.  Make sure that you post to the other thread's mutex before you pthread_exit otherwise the other thread may have more to read but it will be deadlocked.

You should also put the increment of lineCount inside the critical section since it shared between the threads.